# Could not retrieve Sbt 0.13.15 while importing project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am usig Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 with Scala plugin installed. I created my first Scala project with SBT. I get following error while importing SBT project:

```
:: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS problem while downloading module
descriptor:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4.pom:
Read timed out (19336ms)

module not found:
org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4

==== local: tried

C:\Users\Kacper\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4\ivys\ivy.xml

-- artifact org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4!ivy.jar:

C:\Users\Kacper\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4\jars\ivy.jar

==== Maven Central: tried

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4.pom

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivys/ivy.xml

==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivys/ivy.xml

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::
org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4:
not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved
dependency:
org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4:
not found Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required
libraries (see C:\Users\Kacper\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.14 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server
VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in
8.0
```

I get the same error while getting sbt 0.13.15 and 0.13.14.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Also, you might want to open `C:\Users\Kacper\.sbt\boot\update.log` to see what that says.

Comment: The problem is with my default Internet Service Provider. When I switched my default internet connection to internet from mobile device it worked like a charm. Any ideas what is wrong when I am connected to my default ISP?